# Regex: how to match every word from a group in any order?

Tags: regex, match, cpu-word

So let's say I want to search for the words `hamburger` and `steak`. The regex should match/return true only when both words are found, in either order. i.e.

The would return `true`

```
I like hamburgers and steak
I like steak and hamburgers
```

While these would return `false` since only one of the words is matched

```
I like hamburgers
I like stake
```

Hopefully, someone can help me out with this. Ideally, there is a simple solution to this, since these queries will be generated by PHP and the user could enter unlimited words to search for (as opposed to this example, where only 2 are used), so complex solutions could be difficult to implement/debug

Anyway, thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern:

```
^.*\b(?:hamburgers\b.*\bsteak|steak\b.*\bhamburgers)\b.*$
```

This would match for the keywords `hamburgers` and `steak`, in any order.

### Demo